# How to use the multiple values fetched by the regex in following request in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have extracted all the values I needed in the response using a single regex. Now I want to form my request with the extracted values. The values are stored in single variable for ex: `mcdh_1 , mcdh_2` etc. and the number of variables differs in each response.

How to form a request with these dynamically created variables. ?

Comment: I need to give something like in the request as : cdhid=mcdh_1&cdhid=mcdh_2 and goes on . i have to append cdhid to the values everytime

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible with some scripting, for instance take the following steps for adding dynamic parameters to [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of the request, you need to parametrise
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   int params = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("mcdh_matchNr"));

   for (int i = 0; i < params; i++) {
       sampler.addArgument("mcdh_" + i, vars.get("mcdh_" + i));
   }
   ```

You'll get something like:

[image: Dynamic parameters]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more JMeter + Beanshell tips and tricks and a kind of Beanshell cookbook.

Comment: I tried adding this to the preproccessor,but my request was null. doesnt look like the request is parsed.